# Marathon exited with status 1

Tags: mesos, marathon, mesosphere

I am installing mesosphere on ubuntu 16.04 xenial .zookeeper and mesos-master and mesos-slave are running fine ,while starting marathon I am getting this issue .
**Required option 'master' not found** .I have created folder in /etc/marathon/conf .These are the steps I am following for marathon .

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/marathon/conf
sudo cp /etc/mesos-master/hostname /etc/marathon/conf
sudo cp /etc/mesos/zk /etc/marathon/conf/master
sudo cp /etc/marathon/conf/master /etc/marathon/conf/zk
sudo nano /etc/marathon/conf/zk ,edit mesos to marathon in the end .

I am attaching the whole logs here,
    Jan 25 14:18:01 master01 cron[859]: (*system*) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/crontab)
    Jan 25 14:18:01 master01 cron[859]: (*system*popularity-contest) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/popularity-contest)
    Jan 25 14:18:01 master01 cron[859]: (*system*php) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/php)
    Jan 25 14:18:01 master01 cron[859]: (*system*anacron) INSECURE MODE (group/other writable) (/etc/cron.d/anacron)
    Jan 25 14:18:29 master01 systemd[1]: marathon.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
    Jan 25 14:18:29 master01 systemd[1]: Stopped Scheduler for Apache Mesos.
    Jan 25 14:18:29 master01 systemd[1]: Starting Scheduler for Apache Mesos...
    Jan 25 14:18:29 master01 systemd[1]: Started Scheduler for Apache Mesos.
    Jan 25 14:18:29 master01 marathon[29366]: No start hook file found ($HOOK_MARATHON_START). Proceeding with the start script.
    Jan 25 14:18:30 master01 marathon[29366]: [scallop] Error: **Required option 'master' not found**
    Jan 25 14:18:30 master01 systemd[1]: marathon.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
    Jan 25 14:18:30 master01 systemd[1]: marathon.service: Unit entered failed state.
    Jan 25 14:18:30 master01 systemd[1]: marathon.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> ## [Breaking Changes / Packaging standardized](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/f208b0b29f9dbd884a084fd27b551ff7b574a955/changelog.md#packaging-standardized)
>
> We now publish more normalized packages that attempt to follow Linux Standard Base Guidelines and use sbt-native-packager to achieve this. As a result of this and the many historic ways of passing options into marathon, we will only read `/etc/default/marathon` when starting up. This file, like `/etc/sysconfig/marathon`, has all marathon command line options as `"MARATHON_XXX=YYY"` which will translate to `--xx=yyy`. **We no longer support `/etc/marathon/conf` which was a set of files that would get translated into command line arguments. In addition, we no longer assume that if there is no zk/master argument passed in, then both are running on localhost.**

Try to keep config in the environment.

```
cat << EOF > /etc/default/marathon
MARATHON_MASTER=zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos
MARATHON_ZK=zk://127.0.0.1:2181/marathon
EOF
```

Remember to replace 127.0.0.1:2181 with proper Zookeeper location.

Comment: Thanks a lot .I have added this to etc/default/marathon  ,its working fine.Could you please tell me the reason why its happened and even reinstall , it was not working  .

Comment: It's [here](https://github.com/mesosphere/marathon/blob/f208b0b29f9dbd884a084fd27b551ff7b574a955/changelog.md#packaging-standardized)

Comment: Hi janisz ,for cluster how ll I set up .I have added MARATHON_MASTER=zk://127.0.0.1:2181,**.**.***:2181/mesos
MARATHON_ZK=zk://127.0.0.1:2181,10.**.**.**:2181/marathon,but marathon unable to register in mesos .Please suggest .

Comment: What error do you get? Config in that form if correct: `--master zk://zk1.foo.bar:2181,zk2.foo.bar:2181/mesos --zk zk://zk1.foo.bar:2181,zk2.foo.bar:2181/marathon`

Answer (score 2):

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in my case janisz solution did not work as I needed to add `export`

```
cat << EOF > /etc/default/marathon
export MARATHON_MASTER=zk://127.0.0.1:2181/mesos
export MARATHON_ZK=zk://127.0.0.1:2181/marathon
EOF
```